# python to mssql encoding problem

Tags: python, sql-server, character-encoding, pymssql

Greetings

By using **pymssql** library, I want to write data to a MSSQL database however I encounter encoding issues. Here is my sample code to write to the DB:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import _mssql

....
Connection info data here
....


def mssql_connect():
    return _mssql.connect(server=HOST, user=USERNAME, password=PASS, database=DB, charset="utf-8")

con = mssql_connect()
INSERT_EX_SQL = "INSERT INTO myDatabsae (Id, ProgramName, ProgramDetail) VALUES (1, 'Test Characters ÜŞiçÇÖö', 'löşüIIğĞü');"
con.execute_non_query(INSERT_EX_SQL)
con.close()
```

Sadly the data that was written to DB is corrupted:

[image]

The Collacation of my mssql db is: `Turkish_CI_AS`
How can this be solved?

Comment: Does specifying the string explicitly as unicode help? e.g. `INSERT_EX_SQL = u"INSERT INTO myDatabsae (Id, ProgramName, ProgramDetail) VALUES (1, 'Test Characters ÜŞiçÇÖö', 'löşüIIğĞü');"`

Comment: If I unicode the query, I get such error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 84-85: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a possible solution](http://blog.csdn.net/kungbx/archive/2010/06/18/5678779.aspx):

The key is `INSERT_EX_SQ.encode('your language encoder')`.
Try this instead:

```
con.execute_non_query(INSERT_EX_SQ.encode('your language encoder'))
```