# Connecting to SQL Server with pypyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I need to send unicode to SQL Server with Python 2.7.  I [failed with pymssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024041/unable-to-send-unicode-cleanly-to-sql-server-using-pymssql).  I'm now trying to get `pypyodbc` working (as opposed to `pyodbc`), as it gives [working unicode examples](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/wiki/A_HelloWorld_sample_to_access_mssql_with_python).  The problem is that the connection string in the example doesn't look like anything I recognize.  I looked at [this](https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/blob/master/sqlservertests.py), and, after a little trial and error, constructed this string:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='MyServer';UID='me';PWD='MyPassword';DATABASE='db'")
```

Got back a `DatabaseError` focused on the connection string:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in __init__(self, connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly, **kargs)
---> 2 conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='MyServer';UID='me';PWD='password';DATABASE='db'")

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in __init__(self, connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly, **kargs)
---> 2273         self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in connect(self, connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)
---> 2321         check_success(self, ret)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in ctrl_err(ht, h, val_ret, ansi)
---> 919                 raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)

DatabaseError: (u'08001', u'[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.')
```

I know my credentials are correct because I've used them to connect successfully using pymssql.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the `server`, `uid`, `pwd`, and `database` attributes of the connection string:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;UID=me;PWD=password;DATABASE=db")
```

Since `pypyodbc` mentions compatibility with `pyodbc`, take a minute to look over the [pyodbc connection string docs](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings) and [pyodbc.connect()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#Functions) examples. I use this syntax in pyodbc:

```
cnxn = connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost', database='test', uid='me', pwd='me2')
```

Answer (score 3):

Leaving out the port number (1433) in the connection string, threw errors at me from a Linux client (but not Windows 7). It's probably a configuration issue but I didn't have time to chase it.

Putting this out there, in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I my case this code working

```
cnxn = connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost', database='test', 
uid='me', pwd='me2')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**