# sqlalchemy+mssql+python3 query encoding

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, unicode, sqlalchemy, encode

I'm new to sqlalchemy and am working on a small code that fetches data from my company's MS SQL server.

For some reason, the following query returns None. Even though the same query statement works perfectly when typed in an MS SQL console(in pycharm/datagrip).

It seems the problem is caused by the Chinese characters ("南宁市") in the where clause. I can query without any problem as long as there is no special(Chinese) characters in the where clause.

I am wondering if there is a way to solve the issue? Your input will be greatly appreciated.

```
>>from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>engine = create_engine(****, connect_args={'charset':'GBK'})
>>conn = engine.connect()
>>rsps = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM COMPINTRODUCTION WHERE CITY='南宁市'").fetchone()
>>rsps is None
True
```

Software environment:

```
Client OS: Windows 10
DB Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2008
DB Charset: cp936
sqlalchemy version: 1.2.13
pymssql version: 2.1.4
python version: 3.6 (Anaconda)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024041/unable-to-send-unicode-to-sql-server-using-pymssql

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is caused by pymssql. I switch to odbc and the problem is gone.